# Accessing C++ template variables in GDB

Tags: c++, templates, gdb

I am trying to debug a core dump and want to access the variables implemented using template classes in C++.

I have taken an objdump of symbols in my executable file which has the following as one of the symbol
`hmapnspace::HandleMapParameters<(hmapnspace::HandleType)1>::m_arHandleArray`

but when I try to access this variable in gdb it gives me the following error:

```
(gdb) p hmapnspace::HandleMapParameters<(hmapnspace::HandleType)1>::m_arHandleArray
No type "HandleMapParameters<(hmapnspace::HandleType)1>" within class or namespace "hmapnspace".
```

How can I correctly access this variable?

Answer (score 4):

At times, gdb has seemingly weird ideas about names in C++ programs. To overcome, try typing

```
print 'hmapnspace::HandleMapPar
```

and press Tab for completion (note the single quote, you have to use it).

You can also figure out the address of the variable and say something like

```
print *(int*) 0xdeadbabe
```

Handy when you need to watch a value whose name is not in scope.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried accesing the variable inside ' ' but it tells me that variable is pointing to an inavlid memory area. I know this is not correct as I have references from this data structure which are giving me the correct/expected values.

Comment: The single quotes fixed the issues I was having. Thanks a bunch for suggesting it. If there are any reference pages that explain such idiosyncrasies, it would be much appreciated if you'd let us know!

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is a static member variable.  If not, are you in the right context (frame)?

Did you press Tab like n.m. suggested?  I've noticed that gdb doesn't handle typecasting at the command line very well.

Finally, recent versions of gdb (e.g., 7.2) handle templates far better than earlier versions.  For example, you can now easily set breakpoints within a template function or template class, and gdb appropriately puts breakpoints in all template versions of the function.  I don't know if these gdb improvements apply to what you are doing, however.